# Installing drivers for my NetGear AC600 A6100 without internet access, is it possible?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I downloaded many different versions of this driver (not at the same time of course) on to a USB stick, but no matter which one I use, Ubuntu never seems to acknowledge the fact that it's there. I have no idea how to install the files from the USB to the computer. I've tried to open the install files in the terminal, but as soon as I check the box that allows these files to open in terminal, it immediately unchecks itself. I suppose this whole thing would be easier if there was a way for that computer to use another computer's wifi connection via usb temporarily, but to my knowledge, no such idea exists. The only info I have is that my usb adapter is a NetGear a6100 ac600.

Comment: 1. I have Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 installed on my computer
2. My network adapter (NetGear a6100 ac600) is plugged in and it was recognized as a device, but nothing pops up for wireless connections. (Only wired connections and proxy servers)
3. To be clear, my machine is an OptiPlex 780
4. The driver I tried to install was  rtl8812au. (I got the files off of github, but I don't have the exact links) I thought my pc used a realtek chipset, but that might not be the problem as I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to this type of computer issue.
Sorry about the narrative issue, I was tired...

Comment: OK, but your comment also does not explain the exact steps youve taken or the exact problem you encounter. If you still need help with this, use [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1366134/edit) to add details. A significant edit will "bump" your question to the top of active. The more details you can provide, the better chance that someone will understand the issue enough to help suggest a solution.  You should detail every step you took in your attempt to install the driver and the result of each action.  Include all commands, outputs, and errors.